# What kind of camera trickery enables this "zoning out in shock" effect?

Tags: cinematography, babylon-5

One of many memorable moments in the *Babylon 5* sci-fi television series comes in the middle of Season 3 Episode 10, "Severed Dreams" (by itself this episode is chock full of dramatic, significant, and memorable moments), when Captain Sheridan receives shocking news that brings a long-brewing conflict abruptly to a head. There's a brilliant camera effect as Sheridan sits down, which somehow looks like the kind of feeling you get when reacting with extreme shock:

[image: gif of the moment]

It's at about 2:00 in this video:

**Is there a name for this effect, and how is it done?**